# Image segmentation service

Tags: computer-vision

hope you are well.

Does any one knows any service where I can send an image an return its segmentations areas, like using Meta's SAM (https://segment-anything.com/ )?

If not, does any one knows a guide on how to deploy a model like it using Azure ML?

Thanks!